# 2 Divs next to eachother

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a logo and a sidebar next to eachother, but it just won't work. The logo container needs to be centered at the top. And the sidebar needs the be at the top-left Can you help me? I already tried float, no succes. :(

code:

```
<body>
    <center>
        <div id="logo1">
            <div id="logo2"></div>
        </div>
    </center>

    <div id="sidebar1">
        <a href="https://test.com/" target="blank">
            <div id="test1"></div>
        </a>
    </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
#test1 {
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid;
margin-top: 15px;
margin-left: 22px;
background-image:url('Afbeeldingen/2.png');
height: 45px;
width: 45px;
}

#test1:hover {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 22px;
    background-image:url('Afbeeldingen/1.png');
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
}

#sidebar1 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    background-image:url('Afbeeldingen/lol.png');
    height: 1080px;
    width: 118px;
}

#logo1 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 700px;
}
```

Comment: Did you have a link to your website?

Comment: `<center>` tag is deprecated, you should use `margin: auto` instead, also you've negative margins

Answer (score 2):

Ok, This is what you have to do :

- You need to remove the display:inline-block from #logo1
- And instead of just writing margin-top:10px , you need to use margin:0px auto, or you could write margin:10px auto. By this, it will center your #logo1 div.
- But to center a "div" , you need to have another container(div) that wrap within your div. So that it will know, from which side to which side that it will have to be "centered".
- For that reason, you will need to create another div or container around your #logo1 div, and lets assume it is called "right" (see the code below).
- And for this div/container to be just beside your sidebar, it will need to have a relative position same as your sidebar. Now, you can just float both of your #sidebar1 and also your #logo1 to the left.
- Thus, you dont have to use that negative margin for your sidebar anymore (remove that). If you wanted to use the negative margin, you have to use the absolute position in this case. But you will then have to restructure your whole #logo1 div which will create a lot of works.

This is the full code for your reference :

HTML code :

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar1">
        <a href="https://test.com/" target="blank">
            <div id="test1">This is sidebar</div>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="logo1">
            <div id="logo2"><This is logo</div>
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

And use this CSS :

```
        #container{
    width:1000px;
    height:1080px;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #000;
    }

    #test1 {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 22px;
    background-image:url('Afbeeldingen/2.png');
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;
    }

    #test1:hover {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid;
        margin-top: 15px;
        margin-left: 22px;
        background-image:url('Afbeeldingen/1.png');
        height: 45px;
        width: 45px;
    }

    #sidebar1 {
        display: inline-block;
        position:relative;
        float:left;
        border: 1px solid;
        background-image:url('Afbeeldingen/lol.png');
        height: 1080px;
        width: 118px;
        border:1px solid red;
    }

    #right{
       position:relative;
       float:left;
       margin-top:0px;
       width:870px;
       height:100px;
    }

    #logo1 {
        position:relative;
        border: 1px solid;
        margin: 0px auto;
        height: 100px;
        width: 700px;
    }
```

Comment: please add some explanation so that asker can know what he is doing wrong

Comment: Oh sorry, im new here. noted that, and i have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/Le6PH/

You should do:

- Remove the negative margins (If you don't know what you are doing, don't use negative margins)
- Remove the `<center>` tag (This tag is deprecated since EVER)
- Remove the margin of your logo
- Add a wrapper div around your whole structure
- Add the following CSS to that div

CSS

```
.wrapper{
    position:relative;
    width:818px; /* sidebar width + logo width */
}
```

- Change position:relative; to position:absolute for your logo & sidebar divs.
- Add `top:0;` for both divs
- Add `right:0;` for the sidebar div

**EDIT:**

With a centered logo, like this (http://jsfiddle.net/Le6PH/1/) you'll need to change 2 things:

- Add a `margin-left:118px;` to the logo div
- Change the width of the wrapper to width of logo + margin logo + width of sidebar.

Comment: Almost, I just want the logo to be centered.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xZDFj) ?

```
#test1 {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 22px;
  background-image:url('Afbeeldingen/2.png');
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
}

#test1:hover {
  background-image:url('Afbeeldingen/1.png');
}

#sidebar1 {
  position:absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-image:url('Afbeeldingen/lol.png');
  height: 1080px;
  width: 118px;
}

#logo1 {

  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 700px;
}

<div id="sidebar1">
    <a href="https://test.com/" target="blank">
        <div id="test1"></div>
    </a>
</div> 
<div id="logo1">
        <div id="logo2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try floating your div, it should look like this..

```
<div class="row">
 <div id="log"></div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.row{
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: no succes, it still looks like the logo takes up the whole line

Comment: Have you try applying a fixed width ?? then applying margin: 0 auto;

Comment: try some like what i have applied in the answer above

Comment: inline-block works just fine, it's a good alternative for floats